# How Can I in WP7 VB.Net Add An Event Handler For A WebClient?

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, webclient, c#-to-vb.net

So I'ved found a lot of samples of this in C# like the following

```
client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
```

However in VB.Net for my WP7 project I write it like this

```
    client = New WebClient()
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += New DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged)
    client.OpenReadCompleted += New OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted)
```

And it doesn't work. Any ideas why? I've been out of programming for a while and I'm looking to mess around and make an app or two for a friend. Any help or a push in the right direction would be awesome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use VB, but a quick search gave me:

```
AddHandler client.OpenReadCompleted, AddressOf myEventHandler
```

Comment: +1 An exact translation would be `AddHandler client.OpenReadCompleted, New OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted)` but `AddressOf client_OpenReadCompleted` might work too

Comment: Not at home, but it's giving me an error still. Any other ideas? Need me to post more code?

Comment: I've just checked, the construction works perfectly. Have you added a handler function? 

Class MainWindow 

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
        Dim client As New ServiceReference1.Service1Client
        AddHandler client.GetDataCompleted, AddressOf MyHandler
        client.GetDataAsync(100)
    End Sub

    Sub MyHandler(sender As Object, args As ServiceReference1.GetDataCompletedEventArgs)
        tbResult.Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub() tbResult.Text = args.Result)
    End Sub

End Class

Comment: In your case the handler should look like:
Sub client_OpenReadCompleted(sender As Object, args As System.Net.OpenReadCompletedEventArgs)

End Sub

Comment: Thanks, just had a type in the Sub X_X